# Use htaccess to redirect wordpress non-existent page to homepage

Tags: htaccess

For seo reasons I need to redirect domain.com/index.html and domain.com/index.htm pages to homepage without breaking anything. I tried some options so far but none of them work. Plain Redirect 301 commands get the site into redirecting loop. Here is what I've got so far

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [R=301] # this two lines
  RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ - [R=301] #  added by me
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.htm\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.htm$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1index.php [R=301,L]
```